# Assets don't load in spring 4.1.7

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to create resources folder and load assets from this folder inside jsp files. What I did was adding the following lines to main-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/css/**" location="/resources/css/" />
```

Placing `resources/css`, `resources/js`, `resources/images` folders on the same level as `WEB-INF` and `META-INF`.

And in the jsp file:

```
<link href="/resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

But it doesn't load css files. Trying to access .css file from the URL gives me 404 error:

```
http://localhost:8084/resources/css/main.css/
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Change config to:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

And try this:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Don't forget include taglib at the top of your jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```